# Showing holiday events on fullcalendar v3 as in easemytrip mobile view calendar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'today',//'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'prev,next'
                },
                views: {
                    month: { // name of view
                        titleFormat: 'MMM YYYY'
                        // other view-specific options here
                    }
                },
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'Today',
                },
                defaultDate: '2023-06-09',
                fixedWeekCount: false,
                showNonCurrentDates: false,

                navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                dayClick: function (date) {
                    alert(date.format() + "\n" + calEvent.title);
                },
                eventClick: function(calEvent) {
                        alert(calEvent.title);
                },
                eventSources: [
                    // your event source
                    //'/feed1.php',
                    //'/feed2.php',
                    {
                        events: [
                            {
                                title: 'FULL',
                                start: '2023-06-11',

                            },
                            //for holidays
                            {
                                title: '1',
                                start: '2023-06-11',
                                color: '#FFE3A2',
                                textColor: '#000',
                                className: 'circle_dot'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'AVAILABLE',
                                start: '2023-06-12',
                                color: '#257e4a',
                                textColor: '#ffffff',

                            },
                            //for holidays
                            {
                                title: '2',
                                start: '2023-06-12',
                                color: '#FFE3A2',
                                textColor: '#000',
                                className: 'circle_dot'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'FULL',
                                start: '2023-06-23',
                                color: '#e66d1d'
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'AVAILABLE',
                                start: '2023-06-28',
                            }
                        ],
                        color: 'black',     // an universal option!
                        textColor: 'yellow', // an universal option!
                        className: 'text-center'
                    }
                ]
            });

        });
```

```css
       .circle_dot {
            font-size: 9px;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            background: #FFE3A2;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #000;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-weight: 500;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

[image: mobile view calendar from easemytrip.com]

I am using fullcalendar v3 in my project. I want to show holidays on the calendar, as shown on attached image marked in red square box.

It should show following as:

---

1. on the top - it will show total holidays of each month
2. it should number 1,2,3 like badge on dates which has holidays for each month
3. at the bottom of the month it should describe the badge with the holiday name for each month

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question, or a problem statement. And "how to" is a bit too vague. This site is not a free write-my-code, design-my-solution or do-my-thinking service. We'll _help_ you with your attempt to solve your problem / implement your requirement. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What exact issue(s) are you facing? Please read [ask] for further guidance on how to ask a useful question. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson the question has been modified

Comment: You've told us what you want, what is stopping you?  AFAICT there is nothing in your code that tries to implement what you've described - have you tried something which isn't working, or are you expecting others to do everything for you?  As already pointed out, SO is not a code-writing service.  [Research your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6089612), try to implement something, and ask questions here when you get stuck, showing what you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Agreed...this is just your basic calendar code, it does not include any attempt to do what you are asking about. If you want someone to do it all for you, please hire a freelance programmer. If you'd like some (free) help from this community, please show that you genuinely tried to help yourself first, and then come to us with a _specific_ issue, if you have one. Stackoverflow is an encyclopaedia of useful, widely applicable programming questions about problems that many people might reasonably encounter when writing their code. It's not a helpdesk or an outsourcing provider. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found an event - eventAfterAllRender and wrote a function to achieve my task

```js
                eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
                    $('.holidaycount').html('').hide();
                    $('#holidays-list').html('');

                    var loop = 0;
                    $('.circle_dot').each(function () {
                        loop++;
                        $('#holidays-list').append("<p class=\"holidayName\"> <span class=\"holidayNo\">" + loop + "</span>" + $(this).find('.fc-title').text() + "</p>");
                        $(this).find('.fc-title').text(loop);
                        $('.holidaycount').show();
                    });
                    $('.holidaycount').html(loop + ' Holidays');
                },
                eventSources: [
                    '/home/getcalendar?bid=test',
                    '/home/getholidays',
                ]
```

```html
<p class="holidaycount"></p> - This line is above calendar month

<div id="holidays-list"></div> - this line is below calendar month
```